# Not getting output in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have downloaded the latest version of npm and nodejs and I am using Quickstart for cloning but then also I am not getting the output.

After typing npm start in git bash.I am getting the below error:

Please include the following file with any support request
c:\web-dev\project\myapp\npm-debug.log.

Which file I have to include??

Comment: This can't be the only message you get. Provide full exception or what's in the log file.

Comment: That's generated log file, it says include that file if You are submitting support request on some forum/git etc., open that log and paste it here